# Resetting Views in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, view, textview

My `ListView` is a simple ListView, but he has problems.
I am using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` called `adapter` and  I want the TextView to bold and the background to change when an item is clicked.  I also want the other previously affected ListView item to reset itself.

Below is the code for the `onListItemClick` event.  This code resets visible list items. and correctly bolds the selected item.  However, when the user scrolls random `TextViews` are bolded, I presume because views are being recycled.

So, onClick I want to reset any previously clicked textViews and bold the clicked item.

My not working as expected code:

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

            //Tablet
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++)
            {                   
                View mView = listView.getChildAt(i);

                if (mView != null)
                {
                    //Reset Bold text to default
                    TextView mtv = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
                    mtv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.itemlayout);
                    ll.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
                }
            }       

            TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Name);
            tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.itemlayout);
            ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashboard_list_selector);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is normal, as you said the recycler uses old views off the screen instead of creating new ones. What you need to do is to change your adapter, the logic you need has to be implemented also in your getView method. Moreover you need your adapter to support different type of items in order to use different backgrounds.

Take a look to this [example](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296), the example has a different goal but it applies the solution you need.

Sorry but there is not a quick solution. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As was previously pointed out the problem you are having is based on Android reusing views to speed the scrolling of listview. The I have fixed this in the past is to maintain a parallel array that tracks if the item should be bolded.  In the getView code, check the flag in the items position if it is true bold it, otherwise unbold it (you have to set it back to its default state). Then when a user clicks an item switch the flag and call `notifyDataSetChanged`. This will force a redraw and bold the selected item.